# Does SVN have a property to always resolve conflicts a particular way?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'd like to have a particular version-controlled file always be clobbered by the head revision when I do an SVN update, instead of manually having to resolve it every time I update.  Does such a property exist?  Or, less likely, does Tortoise SVN have its own option for that?

**Edit:** Some more explanation - there is a particular built file which gets checked in by a build machine; when working locally, I recompile that file myself if I'm working on its source.  When I do an update on my entire repository, I really don't care if that particular file gets clobbered, since I'll just recompile it myself regardless.  Force syncing is not really an option, because I don't want to accidentally clobber my source files, just these particular exceptions.

Comment: No such property exists. What are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: Sounds like this file might not belong under version control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, there is not any built-in functionality for this.

Answer (score 3):

in subversion update command in a switch called *--accept :

`svn up --accept [postpone|base|mine-full|theirs-full|edit|launch]`

which triggers the interactive conflict-resolution.

Same is possible in TortoiseSVN. Dialog shows up if first conflict occured

Comment: This would apply to all files covered by the update, not the specific file I am interested in, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that called a force sync to head?

Comment: So what? <filling space up to 15 chars>

Comment: You can force sync to head revision all files for which you do not want to be bothered with manual resolution.

Comment: Can you specify that on a per-file basis though without doing the sync's themselves on a per-file basis?